# Can ggtern find the intersection of two lines?

Tags: r, ggplot2, data-visualization, ggtern

With the following code, I have created segments in the ternary diagram. The ternary diagram is shown below.
`

```
library(ggtern)
    DATA <- data.frame(x = c(0,0,0),
                       y = c(1,0.6,1),
                   z = c(0,0.4,0),
                   Series = c("yz"))
ggtern()+
  geom_segment(data=DATA,mapping=aes(x=x,y=y,z=z,
                                     xend=c(0.4,1,0.1),
                                     yend=c(0.0,0,0),
                                     zend=c(0.6,0,0.9)
                                     ))
```

`

[Please click on this to view the figure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KJLhL.png)

The intersection points are circled using a marker in the paint application, I want to find the exact location of those points in the ternary diagram. Is it possible using ggtern?

Comment: you mean without doing the algebra stuff?

Comment: yeah even let me know algebra. Thanks.

Comment: the algebra [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24038066/r-find-the-point-of-intersection-of-two-lines-connecting-4-coordinates?rq=1) or [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14782398/checking-if-lines-intersect-and-if-so-return-the-coordinates?rq=1)